# PHPUnit testing project generated with Composer

Tags: php, phpunit, classloader, composer-php

I have a project generated with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) which has a dependency on PHPUnit. Now I have

- `dir1` -> PHPUnit stuff
- `dir2` -> project stuff

If I go into the project directory and run PHPUnit, it complains about loading `ClassLoader.php` twice:

- PHPUnit requires it in `vendors/autoload.php`
- The application code (bootstrap) requires it

How can I resolve this double-inclusion?

Comment: can you tell us how you run phpunit?

Comment: directory where I pulled phpUnit 3.7 has bin directory. phpunit from that bin is ln -s to /usr/local/bin so I can call it from everywhere (which works for a proj that has nothing to do with composer)

Comment: the answer could be customize your bootstrap but I'm not sure

Comment: What I've done is I have further namespaced the ClassLoader, so there is no clash. But that is a moronic solution.

Comment: Which classloader is that loading? The one from Composer?

Comment: Yes, the composer autoloader, he is responsible for autoloading the aplication, also the tests

Comment: Why don't you put the autoload file of PHPUnit to you bootstrap file? You can do this by editing you `phpunit.xml.dist` file. You need to edit an attribute called `bootstrap` on the main `phpunit` element. It should point to you bootstrap file.

Comment: Doesn't matter how I load the bootstrap (it is in the phpunit.xml already).

Comment: Please put the error message with it's text verbatim into your question. Also this is either a flaw in how the package was done or the way how you configured your computer I'd say.

Comment: Did you try to `require_once` the vendor file instead of `require` ?

Comment: @AdrienBrault Yes, I tried require_once, but that was a flaw, since the file is required once already. We're talking about two different files:`phpUnit/vendors/autoload.php` and `myProject/vendors/autoload.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a certain composer version [citation needed], class loader got "namespaced" with a long name, thus enabling more composer based projects to work together, this is a non issue from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the copy of PHPUnit being installed using Composer, which should be `vendor/bin/phpunit`. See `composer.json`, `tests/composer.json`, and the "Tests" section of `README.md` in this github repo for examples: https://github.com/phergie/phergie-irc-parser

Comment: PHPUnit installed using Composer was the source of trouble in the first place :). Now they play nice.